# Resque number of workers is not accurate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, resque

In my Resque Web UI, it says that currently N of M Workers Working. In this case, M is not right. This happened because I rebooted a couple of Resque instances without shutting down the workers first, I'm guessing a SIGKILL leaves the worker as active in the Redis cache.

The number of Resque instances I am running is constantly growing and shrinking depending on the queue/system load at any given time. Is there anyway possible that I can update the number of actual workers running according to Redis so that it is always in sync? Anyway to get this number accurate would be great.